# How to show the tooltip for the top layer only in multi-layer plotly graphs?

Tags: python, plotly, tooltip, timeline

I have a multi-layer plotly express timeline showing grey blocks with blue activities on them. Both blocks and activities have a tooltip. When hovering over them, I want to show the tooltip for the top layer only: i.e. when hovering over a blue activity (on the top layer), the tooltip for the activity must be displayed; when hovering over a grey block (on the bottom layer), the tooltip for the block must be displayed.

Now, instead, on a part of the region of some of the blue activities, the grey tooltip is displayed.

This can be reproduced by the following example. The problem shows up especially when hovering over the second activity in both blocks: on the left part of those activities, a grey tooltip is shown.

First, I create two separate plots.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df_blocks = pd.DataFrame({
    "start": ["2023-09-01 10:00:00", "2023-09-01 16:00:00"],
    "end": ["2023-09-01 20:00:00", "2023-09-01 22:00:00"],
    "y": [0, 1],
    "tooltip": ["First block", "Second block"],
    "type": ["block", "block"]
    })

df_activities = pd.DataFrame({
    "start": ["2023-09-01 10:00:00", "2023-09-01 14:00:00", "2023-09-01 16:00:00", "2023-09-01 17:00:00"],
    "end": ["2023-09-01 14:00:00", "2023-09-01 20:00:00", "2023-09-01 17:00:00", "2023-09-01 22:00:00"],
    "y": [0, 0, 1, 1],
    "tooltip": ["First activity", "Second activity", "Third activity", "Fourth activity"],
    "type": ["activity", "activity", "activity", "activity"]
    })


fig_blocks = px.timeline(df_blocks, x_start='start', x_end='end', y='y',
                           hover_data=['tooltip'],
                           color="type",
                           color_discrete_map={"block": '#8C8C8F'},
                           )
fig_activities = px.timeline(df_activities, x_start='start', x_end='end', y='y',
                           hover_data=['tooltip'],
                           color="type",
                           color_discrete_map={"activity": '#85AFFF'},
                           )
fig_activities.update_traces(width=0.5)
```

Then, I combine the two plots into one.

```
fig_combined = go.Figure(fig_blocks)
fig_combined.add_traces(fig_activities.data)
fig_combined.show()
```

This results in the unwanted grey tooltip when hovering over the left part of the blue activities.

See the image below: I hover over a blue area and the grey tooltip appears. However, the blue tooltip should be shown here (obviously).

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The closest way to the intended result would be to add the hover template setting to one side. `fig_combined.data[0].hovertemplate = '<extra></extra>';fig_combined.show()` The result of that setting would be an unseen arrow. I can't think of a way to remove this arrow right now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this does not work, since I do want the tooltip to be shown when hovering over the grey area (and this is not the case in your proposed solution). The thing is that I do not want a grey tooltip when hovering over a blue area.

Comment: Your goal is to display a gray hover template? You should make a picture of your current output graph and add your specific wishes.

Comment: Good suggestion, didn't know this was possible on Stack Exchange (being a rookie ;-)). I added the figure. Hopefully this clarifies my problem.

Comment: I finally understand what you are pointing out. I was also able to confirm the actual events. As far as I know, this does not seem to be an improvement.